# How to find this weird complex number?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $a$ and $b$ be any two complex numbers that are not on the unit circle. How can I find all the complex numbers $\lambda$ on the unit circle which are satisfy the equation
$$\dfrac12(|a+b+\lambda\bar a\bar b|^2-1)=(a+b+\lambda\bar a\bar b)^2-3\lambda(\bar a+\bar b+\bar\lambda ab).$$

I guess that there are only finitely many $\lambda$s has this property (I may be wrong).
However I could not imagine any attempt to solve this problem. Thank you for your concern.

Comment: Could you say something about why you are interested in this (e.g., how did you come up with this equation)? Thanks!

Comment: I have a feeling that you have some background motivation to study this equation. Maybe that could be helpful in understanding how to solve this elegantly.

Comment: What sort of interesting results? Come on, give us some motivation! Cheers!

Comment: Do you have any examples of a solution for a specific $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Well $|a+b+\lambda\bar a\bar b| = |\bar a+\bar b+\bar\lambda ab|$ must be relevent somehow.  And LHS is a difference of squares.... maybe... maybe not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let:

$$\;z=a+b+\lambda \bar a \bar b \quad\iff\quad \;\lambda=\frac{z-a-b}{\bar a \bar b}\; \tag{1}$$

... then the equation becomes:

$$\frac{1}{2}(z \bar z - 1) = z^2 - 3 \lambda \bar z \tag{2}$$

The condition that $\lambda$ is on the unit circle is equivalent to $\;\lambda \bar \lambda = 1\;$ so:

$$\frac{z-a-b}{\bar a \bar b} \cdot \frac{\bar z-\bar a-\bar b}{ab} = 1$$

... therefore:

$$\bar z = \bar a + \bar b + \frac{|a b|^2}{z-a-b} \tag{3}$$

Substituting $\lambda$ $(1)$ then $\bar z$ $(3)$ in $(2)$ results in:

$$\frac{1}{2}\left(z \cdot \left(\bar a + \bar b + \frac{|ab|^2}{z-a-b}\right) - 1\right) = z^2 - 3 \left( \frac{z-a-b}{\bar a \bar b} \right) \left( \bar a + \bar b + \frac{|ab|^2}{z-a-b} \right)$$

... which gives a cubic in $z$, though not a particularly pretty one.